# How to set and call a function with different combinations of parameters

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion

I have a python program (or function) and I want to call it with different values for its parameters.

Suppose the function is:

```
myfunc(x = 0,y = 0,z =0, w=0, ...):
```

I use a command line like this to set parameters:

```
run x=2#3#4--y=1#2--z=5
```

It shows values for x,y, and z (The number of parameters isn't fixed, many could have default values and I want to set arbitrary set of them). I want to call the function with all combinations such as `x=2, y=1, z=5`. For this example there are 6 combinations.

I tried to write it with a loop but i think it must be written recursively, because in loop I don't know when to set and unset variables for a next run.

```
               all_vars = var.split("--")
               cont = True
               while cont:
                   ii = 0
                   for _var in all_vars:
                       _var_name,_var_item_list = _var.split("=")
                       _var_item_list = _var_item_list.split("#")
                       cont = False
                       for var_item in _var_item_list:
                               if not _var_name in args or args[_var_name] != var_item
                                   args[_var_name] = var_item
                       _output_name +=  "_" + _var_name + "_" + str(var_item)
                                   cont = True
                                   ii += 1
                                   break
                               else:
                                   continue
                   if cont and ii == len(all_vars):
                       ctx.invoke(run, **args) # calling the function
```

Comment: Do you want to generate all combinations in optimized manner or just want to check if your other function is callable with given keyword argument ?

Comment: @DeepakTripathi I want to call the function with various possible combinations

Comment: @Ahmad Can there be the case where your function expects default argument and you also want to consider that while generating combinations ?

Comment: @DeepakTripathi Yes, all parameters have default values and I can call the function with arbitarary set of paraments.

Comment: @DeepakTripathi I edited my question to reflect this concern

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by calling randomly? If it is a test case, you should be very *clear* about your inputs, so that you can *assert* the output. If it is to generate some random results, segrgrate mandatory vs non-mandatory arguments. Provide random values to all mandatory arguments. Pick a *random* set of non-mandatory args to mock call them with a *random* value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do this in below manner

```
import itertools
import inspect

def fun(x,y,z, d=3):
    print(x,y,z)
    return x+y+z

params = inspect.signature(fun).parameters # paramters of your function

a = "x=2#3#4--y=1#2--z=5".split("--")
var_names = [x.split("=")[0] for x in a]
values = [map(int, x.split("=")[1].split("#")) for x in a]

tot_comb = [dict(zip(var_names, comb)) for comb in itertools.product(*values)]
for comb in tot_comb:
    print(fun(**comb))
```

**I have included inspect module for the use case if you want to check if your funtion is callable with given keyword arguments or not**

Answer (score 2):

I usually do this in tests scenarios, but using pytest:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize('bar', ['a', 'b', 'c'])
@pytest.mark.parametrize('_x', [1, 2, 3])
def test_foo(bar:str, _x: int):
    print(bar, _x)
```

this code will execute the function test with all the arguments combinations:

```
============================= test session starts ==============================
collecting ... collected 9 items

test_static_models.py::test_foo[1-a] 
test_static_models.py::test_foo[1-b] 
test_static_models.py::test_foo[1-c] 
test_static_models.py::test_foo[2-a] 
test_static_models.py::test_foo[2-b] 
test_static_models.py::test_foo[2-c] 
test_static_models.py::test_foo[3-a] 
test_static_models.py::test_foo[3-b] 
test_static_models.py::test_foo[3-c]
```

Comment: Thanks, I would think about it, however now I would like to be able to call different combinations from command line

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way and without library :

```py
var = "x=2#3#4--y=1#2--z=5"
var = {var_bloc[:var_bloc.index("=")]: var_bloc[var_bloc.index("=")+1:].split("#") for var_bloc in var.split("--")}
#Here var will be {"x":['2', '3', '4'], "y": ['1', '2'], "z": ['5']}

def enumerate_possibility(params):
    if len(params) == 1:
        for k, possible_values in params.items():
            for val in possible_values:
                yield {k:val}
    else:
        key, possible_values = list(params.items())[0]
        for val in possible_values:
            for item in enumerate_possibility({k:v for k, v in params.items() if k != key}):
                yield {key:val, **item}

for possible_param in enumerate_possibility(var):
    myfunc(**possible_param)
```

Comment: Thanks, however I wrote the number of parameters isn't fixed, many of them have default values and I may just want to set arbitary parameters

Comment: I edited my question to reflect this concern

Comment: @Ahmad My bad I've read the question too fast, here is an updated answer (without external library)